# Rails test is converting my array of ints to an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, minitest

I have the following test for the create method on my controller

```
  before :each do
    request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
    request.env["CONTENT_TYPE"] = "application/json"

  end

  test "should post create" do
    params = {
      trip_id: 1,
      schedule: {
        price: 12.50,
        max_size: 1,
        time: "11:00 am",
        wdays: [0,1]
      }
    }

    post :create, params
    assert_response :success
  end
```

When this hits my create method, params[:schedule][:wdays] is changed from [0,1] to ["0", "1"]

This causes my test to fail because the wdays has to be a int array. I thought about doing a .to_i in my validation but that would allow ["hello", "world"] to become [0,0].

Oddly enough, this curl command, which I thought would be doing the same thing, works just fine

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"trip_id":1, "schedule":{"price":12.50,"max_size":1,"wdays":[0,1],"time":"11:00 am"}}' http://localhost:3000/trips/1/schedules
```

**How can I get my test to leave the array as an int array like in the curl?**

**If I can't get this functionality to work as is in the tests, should I change my validation to allow a string of arrays? If I do that, how should I prevent strings like "hello" from being valid?**

This is my current validation:

```
  def valid_wdays
    if !wdays.is_a?(Array) || wdays.detect { |d| !(0..6).include?(d) }
      errors.add(:wdays, "should be an array of ints represeting days of the week")
    end
  end
```

Comment: You should remember that HTTP params only support strings

Comment: then why does the curl work?

Comment: This works in cURL because cURL uses the rails stack to process the request. Your controller test bypasses the full rails stack and basically calls `.to_param` on everything. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e92a0653c01d6203d21a5237b1868118e784830e/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L512-L523 You will have better luck with an integration test, because it actually uses ActionDispatch.

Comment: so does that mean I can't test this route here?

Comment: @bsiddiqui You can do anything, anywhere. Try adding this class to your test, and using this in your params: `wdays: [IntParam.new(0),IntParam.new(1)]` - `class IntParam; def initialize int; @int = int; end; def to_param; @int; end; end`

Comment: That is a total hack, BTW. If it wasn't already obvious. :)

Comment: sorry - I meant, would it be best practice not to test this route here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the request not only accepts JSON (`-H "Accept: application/json"` in curl, `request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'` in the test), but sends data as JSON (`-H "Content-type: application/json"` in curl, nothing in the test).

Try something like

```
post :create, params.to_json, format: :json
```

or

```
post :create, params.to_json, {'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'}
```