# ActionController::Parameters converts integer to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I have defined `user_params` in rails 5, like this:

```
def training_plan_params
  params.require(:training_plan).permit(
    :training_plan_id, 
    :sport_id, 
    :distance,
    lastTrainingStatus: [:duration,:reps,:type,:level],
    trainings: [:text, :order, :level],
    modified: [:level,:duration]
  )
end
```

but when i send the params to rails, like this:

```
{ training_plan: { sport_id: 2, distance: 900 } }
```

it doesn't retrieve the distance in the controller as integer, like this:

```
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"sport_id"=>"2", "distance"=>"900"} permitted: true>

=> training_plan_params[:distance]
=> "900"
```

is there a way to keep its type and not converts it to string?

Comment: From the doc on Hash and Array parameters: _... Rails makes no attempt to guess or cast the type_. If you depend on the object type after receiving the params, you'll have to make the "cast" manually. You can add what you're trying to do, e.g. Active Record accepts strings when using where or other methods to ask for integer columns, so you don't need to do any conversion.

Comment: yes, but it didn't convert automatically; when i do something like

**training_plan_params[:distance]/10.0**
,produces a **type error, because "900" is a string.** 

But, when i define permitted params like this

**permitted_params = ActionController::Parameters.new({as_id: 1, asnot_id: '1'}).permit!**
**permitted_params[:as_id]** 
,produces **1** while **permitted_params[:asnot_id]** produces **"1"**.

so, it keeps the type in a way, but it not when it is send from outside, but rather defined on a rails console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was dealing with the same issue today, and I did some searching around.
I found this post: [Rails test is converting my array of ints to an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934766/rails-test-is-converting-my-array-of-ints-to-an-array-of-strings)

Basically, the issue is with the way you're (we're) using ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest, not with ActionController::Parameters.
I solved this by converting the input to my PUT/POST call with `.to_json` and providing `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` to the PUT/POST call. That then led to the test router treating my data as json and preserving the typings, rather than defaulting to treating things as text.